# python interaction with database and parsing strings?

Tags: python, sql

I have the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from stripogram import html2text
import commands
import os
import urllib2
import sys
import re
import string
response = urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[1])
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
outter = soup.find("div",{"id":"ps-content", "class":"bucket"})
final = outter.find("div", {"class":"buying"})
text = final.findAll(text=True)
asd = str(final)
print os.system("echo '"  +asd + "'| html2text" )
```

and it outputs

```
Publication Date: February 1996  | ISBN-10: 0471121207   | ISBN-13: 978-
0471121206  | Edition: 2
```

I need to do the following two things:

1. read all of the initial info like, **"Publication Date:"** or **"ISBN-10"**  and recognize it as attribute
2. After we know that it is an attribute, I wanna upload it to a sql database so that the publication date is the column that it goes to. All of these are suppose to be one row.

EDIT:I am aware how to use a database with PHP and Java. Im only asking for the syntax to upload given my output. is there a way to write a "Something: to recognize the attribute: value | Attribute: value patter of above?

I mainly want to read in the above answer into an array. where the first part, the part in front of the ":" is the key and the part after it (the ":") is the value

Please comment your code. 
Thanks

Comment: Which SQL database? What is the schema (what do the tables look like)? Which library are you using to connect to it? What have you tried?

Comment: "Please comment your code. Thanks". Brilliant. You obviously have not read  the FAQ, which says that you should provide your own code, and ask for help. We are not "work for free" contractors.

Comment: @BrendanLong I dont have a db yet. however, I will make it to however, you suggest.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Calm down dude, I provided code if you take a look. The part that I didnt know how to, I am asking for comment.

Comment: You have two separate questions.  For the parsing question try *something* (anything) and see where that gets you.  You can post the code you try and any errors here for help.  For the database questions "teach me all about databases and how to use them" is not a good question for StackOverflow.  Read up on your own, implement something (SQLite is easiest) and come back with any *specific* questions for which you can show code.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to scrape a webpage and insert the data you collect into a database. The main components you're going to need to write is the part that will sift out the gunk you're not interested in and store the stuff you are interested in (sounds like you are interested in attributes) in Python variables.

From there, you'll need to perform insertions into a database of some sort. Sqlite is probably the easiest to use as it can be stored as a file on your hard disk. import sqlite3 and read the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html to get started with sqlite3. There are numerous other drivers available for other databases. You will need to devise a SQL schema beforehand if you intend to use a SQL relational database.

In general, this whole process is tedious and more of a task than a question so I don't think anyone is going to provide the code solution you seek.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, was in the process of expanding with some helpful prose.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, almost all database APIs in Python follow [PEP 249 - Python Database API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

> This API has been defined to encourage similarity between the
>   Python modules that are used to access databases.  By doing this,
>   we hope to achieve a consistency leading to more easily understood
>   modules, code that is generally more portable across databases,
>   and a broader reach of database connectivity from Python.

So that should give you the general syntax for any database.

There are various libraries for database access, like [Psycopg2 for PostgreSQL](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/) and the [sqlite3 module for SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). Which one you use depends on the database you want to connect to, but it shouldn't matter at this point since you don't have any code, so just write it for whichever one you like and then you should be able to easily port it later since they all use the DB API.